# Play a video from database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, video, media

I am making a video sharing website  which allows users to login and upload videos. It all works fine! The problem is, using js to play the video doesn't work; instead, the very first video is only played. Here's my code to retrieve videos (php/html)

```
    <?php
    include("conn.php");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY file_id DESC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
      $path = $row['path'];
      $caption = $row['caption'];

  ?>
<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="#" onclick="play()">
      <video  width="600" height="400" id="video">
        <source src="store/vids/<?php echo $path;?>" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </a>
    <div class="desc"><br><?php echo $caption?> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Trending</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Script looks like:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video"); 
function play() { 
  if (video.paused) 
    video.play(); 
  else 
    video.pause(); 
}
```

This thing plays only the *first video* from my db table. Any answer is welcome, including js libraries that would make a job easier.

Comment: Each and every element in the DOM must have a unique ID if it has to have an ID at all. You cannot use the same ID `video` in the loop an expect your javascript to know which one the ID refers to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the targeting of the specific video without requiring ID attributes but using `querySelectorAll` and `querySelector` ( you could also use parent/child/sibling traversal techniques )

If you create a `nodelist` using `querySelectorAll` you can assign the event listener externally rather than using `<a onclick='play()'>` etc and is the preferred method. The `click` event is registered as `this` so you can issue another query to find a child element of `this` using `querySelector`

```
<?php
    include("conn.php");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY file_id DESC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $path = $row['path'];
        $caption = $row['caption'];

?>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="#">
      <video  width="600" height="400">
        <source src="store/vids/<?php echo $path;?>" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </a>
    <div class="desc"><br><?php echo $caption?> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Trending</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php 
    }//close while loop
?>


<script>
    Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > a') ).forEach( a=>{
        a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var video=this.querySelector('video');

            if( video.paused )video.play();
            else video.pause();

            // find other videos that are NOT the one just activated and pause them
            Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('.gallery > a > video') ).forEach( el=>{
                if( el!=video )el.pause()
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Works really fine, appreciate it! Is it possible to pause the video when another one else is clicked on?

Comment: made a small modification which should( I hope) pause other videos - not tested though